# Unable to convert PDF to any Image format in C# With Imagemagick

Tags: c#, .net, imagemagick, ghostscript, file-conversion

this is my first question here so please don't be to harsh on me :) Anyway, let's get right to it:

For an application I need to convert a PDF file to an Image file (Specific format doesn't matter but preferably png or jpg). To get this done, I try to use ImageMagick but when I try to convert anything, it will throw an error.
Now after some research I came to the conclusion I needed to have Ghostscript installed, which I tried to get from the NuGet package manager integrated in Visual Studio 2017. Anyway, when I try to install said package, it throws the following error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression >State
>   Error      Failed to add reference to 'gsdll32'.
>   Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid >assembly or COM component.

I'm trying to accomplish this using Visual Studio 2017 with C#. The API's I am using are: 
`+Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU V7.11.1`
`+GhostScriptSharp V1.3.1.4`
`+Ghostscript V9.2.0 (Throws error)`

In case it is required to understand what I am trying, here is the code that I am trying to compile:

```
using ImageMagick.Configuration;
using ImageMagick.Defines;
using ImageMagick.ImageOptimizers;
using ImageMagick;

using GhostscriptSharp;
using GhostscriptSharp.Settings;
```

```
        public MagickImageCollection PDFOutput;
        public Image Current;
        public org.pdfclown.documents.Page CurrentPage;

        private void BtnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    ImageMagick.MagickNET.Initialize();
                    MagickReadSettings Settings = new MagickReadSettings();
                    Settings.Density = new Density(300, 300);
                    Settings.Format = MagickFormat.Jpg;

                    using (MagickImageCollection Images = new MagickImageCollection())
                    {
                        Images.Add(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                        int Page = 1;
                        int i = 0;
                        foreach(MagickImage Image in Images)
                        {
                            Image.Write("FilePage #" + Page);
                            PDFOutput[i] = Image;
                            Page++;
                            i++;
                        }
                        MessageBox.Show(PDFOutput.Count.ToString());
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception E)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(E.Message);
                }
```

Am I missing something regarding the GhostScipt install? Does it only work when downloaded directly from the GhostScript website?

I hope that I have provided enough context to my problem and I'll be looking forward to any answers I may get on this.

Many thanks in advance!!

Kind Regards,
Melvin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes *GhostScript* is licensed in such a way, that people don't include it in their wrappers/nugets. You need to make sure you have the dll.

You generally have to download it (`gsdll32.dll`), add it to the project and output it to your output path (or anything similar, like install it) so that your application can find the `gsdll32.dll` and load it.

Also note you will need the appropriate bitness aswell

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have downloaded Ghostscript directly now and it did indeed come with the gsdll32.dll. When I try to add it as a reference (right clicked references in solution explorer and added it as a reference), but that throws the same error as before. I'm rather new to this level of programming, so where can I find this output path?
Also lastly, with bitness I assume you mean x32, x64 etc?

Comment: @MelvinWinthagen start by just putting the dll in the output directory, see if that works

Comment: Alright assuming the output directory is C:\Users\Melvin\source\repos\Facturconversietest\Facturconversietest\bin\Debug it is still throwing the same error. I've also tried downloading the x64 version but that also throws the same error.
Putting it in the dll subfolder also yielded no results unfortunately

Comment: Quick update: I found a different api that also offers the functionality that I need so I'll be using that now. But thanks for your time!